# The kind of time format

Tags: php

I have this kind of json to be sent in some endpoint. In the documentation, there is this data that need to be sent back

```
{
  "eventId": "string",
  "eventData": {
    "eventDate": "2016-07-22T19:08:12.474Z",
    "details": [
      {
        "OrderId": "string",
        "ItemId": "string",
        "reason": "string"
      }
    ]
}
```

The question is on eventDate.

What kind of time format is this in PHP?

`2016-07-22T19:08:12.495Z`

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "kind"? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Just wanted to ask the format. because I need to convert any given date to that format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> #### ISO 8601 <sup>[[wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> [*Combined date and time representations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations)
>
> If a time zone designator is required, it follows the combined date and time. For example:
> "**2007-04-05T14:30Z**" or "2007-04-05T12:30−02:00".